# Android how to read .realm file stored in assets and perform CURD on this data

Tags: android, realm

In android Storing .realm file in assets;now i want to read that file and perform CURD operations on the data which i get from file

Comment: Put up the code trials that you have made. No code , No Help !

Comment: `.assetFile()` on RealmConfiguration?

Comment: String copyBundledRealmFile(String outFileName) {
      
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets()
                    .open("data/Test.realm", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            
           
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
       
    }